# What are the risks of adding `/usr/libexec` to `$PATH`?

Tags: command-line, security, path

I want easy access to PlistBuddy, which I wasn't even sure still shipped with macOS (Big Sur 11.3 here).

I found it in `/usr/libexec`, a directory I don't know well, but which contains a large number of executables, some of which I already use. So why isn't `/usr/libexec` in the default `$PATH`?

I prefer a big `$PATH`, and if it's safe, and I would edit my `~/.${SHELL##*/}rc` with something like this:

```sh
export PATH=/usr/libexec:${PATH}
```

instead of adding this:

```sh
alias PlistBuddy=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
```

Is there any reason not to?

Comment: What do you mean with "risk"?

Comment: @nohillside: I’m assuming there’s a reason, maybe security‑related, why a directory with so many executables isn’t, by default, in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Well, most of these commands are rarely used directly.

Comment: Anyway, which risks do you worry about which don‘t also apply to /usr/bin?

Comment: I’m not concerned about `/usr/bin` either – I want to know if there are any reasons, security or otherwise, that `/usr/libexec`’s not there. I assumed the reasoning would be security‑related.

Comment: I'd just create a _symlink_ for it to `/usr/local/bin/PlistBuddy`, e.g.: `sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /usr/local/bin/PlistBuddy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add `/usr/libexec` to your path.

`/usr/libexec` is intended for "system daemons & system utilities (executed by other programs)".  This is the description from the command `man hier`.

So you don't want to directly run something from there by mistake.

If you have a reason to run one of those executables directly it is better create an alias.